# Corrupt PDF email attachment when generated by FPDF and PHP

Tags: php, pdf-generation, fpdf

I have a web application that builds a dynamic PDF with FPDF and allows you to download it. That works fine. When I try to email it to myself as a test instead of downloading, I get an email with a corrupt PDF attachment.

I have tried the code from http://www.astahost.com/info.php/create-email-pdf-file-39on-fly39-php_t6334.html and http://www.daniweb.com/code/snippet217105.html but get the same result each time.

Has anyone come across this or know a way to fix it?

Comment: You've tried the exact code from those to sites, without any changes except maybe $to=..; $from=...; ? The pdf was corrupt in what way? E.g. did the reader rejected it? Or was something missing? Which email client did you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best way to get help here is to *subset* the full text headers and body of a received message, and place them in your question.  Email is *encoded*, and not all email servers pass all types of encoding. The code you're using specifies "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".

Here's a valid JPG encoded with same:

```
--_eba07140-496e-4f3d-91ce-aff8afde8879_
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="DSC03538_AZ_atCape.JPG"

/9j/4Rt/RXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAALAA4BAgAgAAAAkgAAAA8BAgAFAAAAsgAAABABAgAHAAAAuAAA
ABIBAwABAAAAAQAAABoBBQABAAAAwAAAABsBBQABAAAAyAAAACgBAwABAAAAAgAAADIBAgAUAAAA
....
```

Comment: That or use something like PHPMailer (phpmailer.worxware.com) which allows adding attachments from strings. Far safer/easier than trying to build a MIME email yourself.